# Immutable Properties That Shouldn't Be

Tags: ios, swift, properties

I've come across a very strange problem, which I am trying to understand. It appears that instance variables are not working like they should...

```
                self.imageView.setImage(image) // This works.
                self.imageView.image = image // This does not.
```

With the second method, I get the following error. `Cannot assign to property: self is immutable`.

This is the first time it happens to me: I am not doing anything special.
My image view is declared like follows,
`@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!`, and is connected in the storyboard.

The only think I can think of is that I've recently included an Objective-C bridging header; it was working fine yesterday, although I can't seem to make it work normally by removing the bridging header from the build settings.

All this is happening from a `UIViewController` subclass, and I mean class, not struct...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: UIImageView doesn't have a metod called setImage, so I do see how that could work? The correct way to set a image is imageView.image = image

Comment: @NicklasRidewing That's exactly my point. I have no idea what's going on !

Comment: Could it be a third-party library that is causing this issue? What libraries are you including?

Comment: And what happens when you cmd-click on the method, setImage?

Comment: Only in objc, there's a setter of property. I think maybe you #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>?

Comment: @NicklasRidewing, Interesting: I was including "UIImage+PDF" (https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF). Removing it fixes the issue. Which is very confusing...

Comment: @KleinMioke UIImage+PDF includes Foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason behind all this. It's stupid, and I thank Nicklas Ridewing for pointing me in the right direction.

I've included https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF (UIImage+PDF).

This code extends `UIView` with a method defined as

`- (NSImage *) image`.

I renamed it, `pdf_image` and all was fixed, after changing all calls to it in the library. Maybe I'll do a pull request...

Comment: Great that you found out what the issue was. General rule for me, if something behaves like it's not intended to do, start removing external sources and re adding them, util the issue reappears ;)

Comment: @NicklasRidewing absolutely, I should have tried before posting the question ;)